# I installed Python3 using Homebrew - but I didn't get a launcher. What do I do to get one?

Tags: catalina, python

How can I get a Launcher for Python3 on the Mac Catalina? Does installing from Homebrew just not provide one?

Comment: What is a Launcher for python?

Comment: If you want to run a .py script, just enter 'python3 "filename.py"' when you are in the correct folder in terminal and it will run.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already installed your python 3 version with:

> brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python

If you're not familiar with brew, check the documentation: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

In the next step I don't really get your problem properly. You can start any file with python3 <src_to_file/file.py> or just use a source-code editor like VS-Code.

Answer (score 0):

I always install python directly from python.org. The installer comes with the Launcher.app, and the IDLE developer environment.